# Questions about using smart pointers with winsock's addrinfo struct

Tags: c++, function-pointers, smart-pointers, winsock2

I'm trying to handle winsock's addrinfo pointer with the unique_ptr.
After doing some research I found an answer that wasn't really explained very well, so now I'm confused. (The answer I'm talking about: [Smart pointers with addrinfo struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942280/smart-pointers-with-addrinfo-struct))

So my general understanding of unique_ptr says that the syntax is as follows:
`unique_ptr<type of handled data, type of function deleting the data>(pointer, deleter function pointer);`.

A basic example of this would be:

```
void deleteInt(int* ptr){...}

int* ptr = new int;
unique_ptr(int, void(*)(int*)>(ptr, deleteInt);
```

Note how the function type doesn't specify a name and simply has `(*)`.

Now, finally, onto my question:
In the answer I mentioned above, the code does something weird.
Instead of being `unique_ptr<addrinfo, void(*)(addrinfo*)>...` it is `unique_ptr<addrinfo, void(__stdcall*)(addrinfo*)>...` and nobody seems to question it. How so? How does it change the type of the function? What is __stdcall? Why does it even work since `T (name*)()` isn't even valid syntax? Needless to say, simply having `void(*)(addrinfo*)` as the function type doesn't work and spits out a bunch of incomprehensible template errors which I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__stdcall` is a [**calling convention**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/), which controls how function parameters are passed, how the call stack is cleaned up, etc. Your `int*` example does not specify a calling convention for its deleter, so the compiler's default calling convention is used (usually `__cdecl`). But API functions have defined calling conventions for interop purposes, so you must use the correct convention. Almost all Win32 APIs (with few exceptions) use the `__stdcall` calling convention.

Rather than hard-coding the deleter's type, it would be easier to use `decltype` instead and let the compiler deduce the type for you:

```
addrinfo *addr;
getaddrinfo(..., &addr);
unique_ptr<addrinfo, decltype(&::freeaddrinfo)> addrPtr(addr, &::freeaddrinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, I didn't know that such a thing even existed. Could you also elaborate on what it means to use decltype with `&::`? I have never seen it used in such a way.

Comment: @Habitate `&` is the address-of operator, and `::` is the scope operator. The code is taking the address of the `freeaddrinfo` function that is located in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I was a little bit confused about the `&` operator since I thought using a simple function name is the same as passing the pointer. Seems not to be the case with `decltype`.